# Linux CSV - Add a colum from a CSV file to another CSV File

Tags: linux, csv, insert

I'm struggling to create a CSV file from two other ones

Here's what I need

File I want (lot of others lines)

"AB";"A";"B";"C";"D";"E"

Files I have:

File 1:
"A";"B";"C";"D";"E"

File 2:
"AB";"C";"D";"E"

How can I simply add "AB" from File to the 1st position of 1st one, adding one ";" ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk as below. This assumes that you have only **;** character as the field separator. And it is not used anywhere else in the CSV file.

```
$ awk -F\; '{print $2}' file.csv
```